# My Java code is not retrieving all product details,How do I solve this?

Tags: java

```
 public Product getAllProducts(String productType) 
    {       
    Connection con = getConnection();               
    String sql = "select* from product_item where productType='" + productType + "'";
    Product u = new Product();
            try 
            {                   
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        int proID = rs.getInt("productID");
                        String productName = rs.getString("productName");
                        String productTyp  = rs.getString("productType");
                        String productDiscription = rs.getString("productDiscription");
                        int productPrice = rs.getInt("productPrice");                            
                        String productSize = rs.getString("productSize");
                        String productPicURL =rs.getString("productPicURL");                     
                        u = new Product(proID,productName,productTyp,productDiscription,productPrice,productSize,productPicURL);
                   }        
                        con.close();
                    } 
            catch (SQLException | NullPointerException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            return u;
}
```

This is my getAllProduct function, I will send productType attribute which is index. So now I want to retrieve my all data, but It doesnt work,

This may show only last raw of my table, but I wan all the product types of data in my Database,
Please help me, where did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you are fetching all the records you are return only the last record values.

Instead you can use an *ArrayList* to store each record fetched. 
Below snippet will help you know the changes required.

```
Product u = new Product();
ArrayList<Object> productList = new ArrayList<Object>();
try 
            {                   
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        int proID = rs.getInt("productID");
                        String productName = rs.getString("productName");
                        String productTyp  = rs.getString("productType");
                        String productDiscription = rs.getString("productDiscription");
                        int productPrice = rs.getInt("productPrice");                            
                        String productSize = rs.getString("productSize");
                        String productPicURL =rs.getString("productPicURL");                     
                        u = new Product(proID,productName,productTyp,productDiscription,productPrice,productSize,productPicURL);
                        productList.add(u);
                   }        
                        con.close();
                    } 
            catch (SQLException | NullPointerException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
           httpRequest.setAttribute("prodList", productList);
```

Then in *jsp* you can loop through the ArrayList object using *JSTL*. You need to include the taglib library for the same as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

Then you need to make following change in your jsp code for your table data:

```
<c:forEach="${prodList}" var="product">
 <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${product.productID}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.productName}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.productType}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.productDiscription}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.productPrice}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.productSize}"/></td>
        <td><img src="<c:out value="${product.productPicURL}"/>" style="width:304px;height:228px;"></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @ShanSenadheera edited my answer to include changes in jsp page. Hope it will get you going. Do mark the answer as Accepted if helpful.

Comment: Its very helpfull,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public Product getAllProducts(String productType) 
    {

        Connection con = getConnection();
        int index = Integer.parseInt(productType);

        String sql = "select* from product_item where productType='" + index + "'";
        Product u = new Product();
                try 
                {                   
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                        while (rs.next())
                        {
                            int proID = rs.getInt("productID");
                            String productName = rs.getString("productName");
                            String productTyp  = rs.getString("productType");
                            String productDiscription = rs.getString("productDiscription");
                            int productPrice = rs.getInt("productPrice");                            
                            String productSize = rs.getString("productSize");
                            String productPicURL =rs.getString("productPicURL");                     
                            u = new Product(proID,productName,productTyp,productDiscription,productPrice,productSize,productPicURL);
                       }        
                            con.close();
                        } 
                catch (SQLException | NullPointerException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                return u;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: this is also right..But in my program I tested on Array List, So problem solved. This is also right, but the case is i didn't check on this code, so probably it is also right if you not using JSTL to retrieving data. So thank you very much for providing answers to my question. I appreciated that.:) thank you.